# Spring: Derived Queries using 2 clauses?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data

I am currently using [spring derived queries](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) in my application. E.g:

```
Dog findById(String id);
```

Is there a way to add 2 or more clauses to the derived queries? e.g.:

```
Dog findByIdAndOwnerOrderByOwner();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this,

```
Dog findByIdAndOwnerOrderByOwnerDesc(String id, String owner);
```

As long as you use AND or OR to concatenate your query, it should handle multiple clauses. I also believe you need to specify the order by order (ASC/DESC).

Check out [Spring Data JPA](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details) for more information regarding this topic.